# Convert C# format to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, string.format

I am sure this is a simple question for you guys but I don't know what this developer is doing.

```
name = String.Format(MyStringBuilder + "");
```

If I convert this to VB I get the message "operator + is not defined for types system.text.stringbuilder and string".  Same thing if I use &.

Comment: Is whoever wrote that code fired now?

Comment: Rule #1 for converting code between any two languages: start by converting any obscure fragment like that one into a saner variant, then the conversion itself will be far easier.

Comment: Is whoever wrote the code sober now? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the strictest sense, MyStringBuilder in the original code could be a null instance, at which point making an explicit call to .ToString() would throw an exception. The code sample provided would execute properly, however. In VB, you may want to say

```
Dim name As String
If MyStringBuilder Is Nothing Then
   name = String.Empty
Else
   name = MyStringBuilder.ToString()
End If
```

Comment: why not the following to reduce redundancy?

dim name as string = string.empty
if mystringbuider isnot nothing then name = mystringbuilder.tostring()

Comment: Thanks Anthony and everyone else. It looked like an old VB trick to get around Nulls in database queries and I never thought I would see that in C#. I just didn't trust my instincts.
Bill

Comment: @Bill, there are cleaner, more-intuitive ways to do that in C#. `string name = MyStringBuilder != null ? MyStringBuilder.ToString() : string.Empty;`, for one. But even in the original code sample, `string.Format` was superfluous.

Comment: @Anthony,@Bill in VB it could be `Dim name As String = IIf(MyStringBuilder Is Nothing, "", MyStringBuilder.ToString())` In later versions of VB you can use `If` in place of `IIf`

Comment: @MarkJ, I tested IIf yesterday in 3.5, you still get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Anthony Oops, yes. Only `If` would avoid the NullReferenceException because it only evaluates the argument it needs. My bad

Answer (score 11):

It looks as if the person who wrote it is attempting to force an implicit conversion of MyStringBuilder to a string using the + operator in conjuction with the empty string.

To perform this assignment in VB you only need:

```
name = MyStringBuilder.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't make sense to me because AFAICT passing only one argument to string.format doesn't do anything.

Adding "" to the stringbuilder just coerces it to a string.

`name = MyStringBuilder.ToString();` would be how I'd do this in C#. Converting that statement to VB should be loads easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use MyStringBuilder.ToString().  That will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concatenate a StringBuilder object and String together - that wouldn't work :)

```
name = String.Format(MyStringBuilder.ToString() + "");
```

This should compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET you would use a "&" instead of a "+"

This line:

```
name = String.Format(MyStringBuilder + "");
```

Is causing an implicit cast of MyStringBuilder to string (using the ToString() method) in order to use the "+" operator. It's the same as:

```
name = String.Format(MyStringBuilder.ToString() + "");
```

which is the same as

```
name = MyStringBuilder.ToString();
```

which becomes this in VB.NET:

```
name = MyStringBuilder.ToString()
```